# Error: FireSharp's SetAsync and GetAsync not marked as async?

Tags: c#, firebase, fire-sharp

I'm a beginner and recently tried to get started with FireSharp, and even got some data transfered:

> This was my first Code to send data to the server:
>
> ```cs
> public static class Client
> {
>    static IFirebaseClient client;
>
>    static IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
>    {
>        AuthSecret = "MyAuthSecret",
>        BasePath = "MyBasePath"
>    };
>
>
>    public static bool Start()
>    {
>        client = new FirebaseClient(config);
>
>        if (client != null) 
>        {
>            return true; 
>        } else {
>            return false;
>        }
>    }
>
>    public static void Send(Data data)
>    {
>        SetResponse response = await client.SetAsync("Testpath", data);
>    }
> ```

But at the line `SetResponse response = await client.SetAsync("Testpath", data);`, I got the following error message:
`The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.`

I was still able to send data, simply by reducing the line to `client.SetAsync("Testpath", data);`. I knew it wasn't ideal, since I didn't got a response that way, but it worked!

The real problem was, that I didn't managed to come up with such a workaround for `FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("Testpath");`. That way I'm currently unable to get data from the server.

Does anyone have any idea on what the problem could be or how to fix it?

> ## My ideas were:
>
> - Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I put all this in a static class.
> - Maybe the FireSharp Libary is broken in the current version.
> - Maybe I could manually mark the methods as async, since thats whats the error-message saying.
> - Or I could manually change it's return type, as the error-message says.
> - Maybe I understood the whole `"await"` and `"async"` thing wrong.
> - The [manual](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/blob/master/README.md) says, `"FirebaseClient uses Newtonsoft.Json by default.` Maybe that could have anything to do with it.

But I havent tried any of them, since I don't know how. I have no idea whether it is possible and would make sence to change the code of the libary, or whatever the error-message means with `"change the return type"`. I watched a tutorial and looked at the [manual](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/blob/master/README.md), but couldn't find any information about this problem.

I would really appreciate any help since I wasn't able to find any information about this problem on the Internet so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Send method must be `async`

`public static async Task Send(Data data)`